# Apply PHP function to specific keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a script that processes data that is submitted from a third party web service that I don't control. I need to clean up some of the user-submitted data. Specifically, I need to go through each array and reformat all of the first names and last names to be sure they are properly capitalized (Ernest Hemingway instead of ERnest HEMINGWAY).

I have been using ucwords(strtolower()) to fix the capitalization, but I need to apply that method to all of the values stored in the first_name and last_name keys in each array. There are other strings that I don't want to change, only the first_name and last_name values. Here's an example of the array:

```
Array 
(
    [authors] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => Ernest
                        [last_name] => HEMINGWAY
                        [book] => Too many to mention, but I like the Sun Also Rises 
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => john
                        [last_name] => steinbeck
                        [book] => East of Eden
    )

    [actors] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => jOhn
                        [last_name] => WAYNE
                        [occupation] => Just generally a bad dude. 
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => clint
                        [last_name] => eastwood
                        [occupation] => Go ahead. Make my day. 
    )
)
```

Any thoughts on how I can loop through each array and apply ucwords(strtolower()) to only the first_name and last_name values? There are a lot of arrays that need this, so I am hoping to be able to programatically find and format the first_name and last_name values. The array format needs to be the same post-processing, with only the values changed.

EDIT: I am sure that, as suggested below, array_walk_recursive is the way to go. I wasn't able to get it to work, but I did create a new method that does the job. Here it is for reference:

```
protected function _fixCase(array $data)
{
    $newData = $data; 
    foreach  ($newData as $key => $value) {
        switch (true) {
            case stristr($key, 'first_name') || stristr($key, 'last_name'); 
                $newData[$key] = ucwords(strtolower($value)); 
                break; 
            default: 
                ''; 
        }
    }
    return $newData;
}
```

Comment: you may want to have a look at `array_walk_recursive`. The second parameter you get in the callback function will be the key, so just check if that one is equal to `first_name` or `last_name` before you apply you cleanup. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: Keep in mind that not all names will be properly capitalized this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recursively walk the array with a callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key) {
        if ($key === 'first_name' || $key === 'last_name') {
            $item = ucwords(strtolower($item));
        }
    }
);
```

This will alter the items in place (`&$item`) if the `$key` matches what you want to change.

Comment: That makes my comment somewhat redundant... Something with minds and great and alike ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wasn't able to get array_walk_recursive to work, but I'm sure that's due to my own limitations. I ended up creating a function that is probably less elegant, but gets the job done.